# How to dynamicaly search for a string in all TreeView nodes expanding and collapsing nodes matching (or not) the search string?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, search, treeview

I´m trying to implement dynamic search on a treeview component, and I´m almost done with it, except that since it´s a dynamic search based on the textchanged event of a textbox, the first characters of the search string are always found, so the search function expand all nodes because they are a valid match.

The thing is that as the search string becomes more complete, those nodes that were expanded when they had a match, now needs to be collapsed because they no longer match the search string... and this is not happening... I could not find yet a way to collapse and expand the nodes dinamically as the search string changes...

I have uploaded a video and the Visual Studio 2012 solution so you can take a look at it and see where I´m dropping the ball...

This is the code of my function that does the search: (You can see in the video it works as expected, so my problem is the expanding/collapsing of the nodes as they match(or not) the search string.

I´ve implemented some ideas in the "FindRecursive" function to collapse and expand the nodes, but it´s not working as expected. I managed to even put the control in an infinite loop due to my wrong logic.

[Video showing the problem](http://www.screencast.com/t/HHTfGdf80XW)

[Visual Studio 2012 Project + Test File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zWGlBf98V0TUFTenUxNXpRUnM/view?usp=sharing)

```
Private Sub txtFiltroIDs_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilterToolIDs.TextChanged
        ClearBackColor()
        FindByText()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FindByText()
        Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection = tviewToolIDs.Nodes
        Dim n As TreeNode
        For Each n In nodes
            FindRecursive(n)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub FindRecursive(ByVal tNode As TreeNode)
        If txtFilterToolIDs.Text = "" Then
            tviewToolIDs.CollapseAll()
            tviewToolIDs.BackColor = Color.White
            ExpandToLevel(tviewToolIDs.Nodes, 1)
        Else
            Dim tn As TreeNode
            For Each tn In tNode.Nodes
                ' if the text properties match, color the item
                If tn.Text.Contains(txtFilterToolIDs.Text) Then
                    tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    tn.EnsureVisible()        'Scroll the control to the item
                End If

                FindRecursive(tn)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearBackColor()
        Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection
        nodes = tviewToolIDs.Nodes
        Dim n As TreeNode
        For Each n In nodes
            ClearRecursive(n)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearRecursive(ByVal treeNode As TreeNode)
        Dim tn As TreeNode
        For Each tn In treeNode.Nodes
            tn.BackColor = Color.White
            ClearRecursive(tn)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: So in addition to changing the backcolor when you "reset" for a new search, you need to [Collapse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.collapse(v=vs.85).aspx) the nodes as well.  This way only the matches will be expanded and colored with the new search results.  Currently you're doing that with `CollapseAll()`, but that's only when the search box is completely empty.

Comment: Idle_Mind, Thanks for replying...  I tried to add a   tviewToolIDs.CollapseAll() in the beginning of the "FindRecursive" function... It hangs the application..

Comment: You'd also need to suppress repainting while you reset everything and then color/expand the matches.  You can this by calling [BeginUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate(v=vs.80).aspx), performing all the changes, then calling [EndUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.endupdate(v=vs.80).aspx) to allow it to redraw in the new state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my initial comments, try something like:

```
Private Sub txtFiltroIDs_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilterToolIDs.TextChanged
    tviewToolIDs.BeginUpdate()
    tviewToolIDs.CollapseAll()
    ClearBackColor()
    FindByText()
    tviewToolIDs.EndUpdate()
    tviewToolIDs.Refresh()
End Sub
```